# Can functions from the C standard library be used in C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-interoperability

Right now I'm getting familiar with C and the C standard library and I wonder if my knowledge in this area will be useful when I turn to working with C++ at a later time.

Therefore I'd like to know, whether I can use the functions provided by the C standard library in a C++ setting, and also whether and why it would make sense to actually do so.

Comment: @moooeeeep: Note that you have changed the meaning of OP. OP asked for standard libraries, what is a definite yes. While after your edit it asks for C-fucntions, where the answer is "It depends on they were implemented for doing so." I would suggest to reroll that part!

Comment: @Zaibis I thought it might be more interesting to include the more general case, but you are right, the OP asked specifically about the standard library. Please review my second edit.

Comment: @moooeeeep: I'm fine with it. Hopefully Nimit is aswell :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, C++ was originally designed so that any C library can be easily used in C++. Of course this is slightly less true (in particular, if a C library happens to use some C++ keyword like `try` or `dynamic_cast`, it won't work; also, if a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) coded in C++ passed to a C library is raising some exception, you are likely to have a big mess).

The standard practice to use a C header file in C++ is

```
 extern "C" {
 #include <some_c_header_file.h>
 };
```

and most *existing* C header files are designed to cooperate with C++ by actually containing stuff like

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 //// most of the header material goes here, C style

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }; // end extern "C"
 #endif
```

In practice, many C standard headers have equivalent C++ headers wrapping things like above (and also in `namespace std`). Eg C `<stdio.h>` is C++ `<cstdio>` -but you often should prefer genuine C++ streams (`<iostream>`), however `printf`-like routines are usually more [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) friendly mixed with [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html).

However **C and C++ are very different languages.** You should code in idiomatic C++11 (using standard C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), `auto`, [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), ...)

Some standard C functions are not very useful in idiomatic C++. For example, you are unlikely to use *directly* `malloc` in *genuine* C++ (at least prefer `new` -which is still very low level and no more in the C++ spirit-, more likely use a lot the containers and the smart pointers *without* dealing manually with heap allocation). But [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) functions (notably [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) ....) are quite useful in C++. [`longjmp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) is likely to be incompatible with C++ exceptions.

BTW, C++ has evolved *a lot* in this century. Don't learn C++98 but at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (there are *tremendous* differences between them) and perhaps [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14). Use a *recent* compiler ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)); in december 2015, that means [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) at least or [Clang/LLVM 3.7](http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) at least. Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info in the compiler (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11`)

**C++** (that means C++11 at least) **is a *difficult* programming language**, considerably more complex than C is. You'll need weeks of reading to learn some of it, and good coding style and discipline is essential (you can easily write very crappy code in C++). Start with [*Programming: Principles & Practice Using C++*](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/)

I believe that if you only know C, reading [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (and studying a bit of Scheme) *before* learning C++ is worthwhile.

The notion of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is very important, both in C and probably even more in C++. You absolutely need to understand it (see C.Lattner's [blog on it](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)) and [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) it.

You will also learn a big lot by studying (and perhaps contributing to) some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and its source code. Hence I recommend using Linux.

Comment: And if you do want to use a C library which has e.g. a struct field named `try`, you can simply `#define try try_` or similar before you `#include` it.

Comment: @Claudio The C++ counterparts are primarily used to insert the symbols into the `std::` namespace, not to add the `extern "C" {'. At least on my machine, it works perfectly fine to include all the C standard headers directly, inserting the symbols into the global namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes there is no C++(11) equivalent in the standard library, e.g., arithmetics with dates (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669430/1025391)

Comment: I wouldn't be too religious about writing idiomatic C++: Do whatever is most *simple*. All other concerns are of secondary importance. For me, it means that I tend to use the `printf()` family of functions over the C++ iostreams, because doing correct formatting with `cout` is a PITA, while the C version is usually quite readable and straight-forward.

Comment: I was much more thinking of containers, smart pointers than of streams

Comment: My recommendation to read SICP before learning C++11 is still a strong one, in particular if you only know C

Comment: Aren't closures and anonymous functions the same?

Comment: @Columbo Closures capture state, functions do not. I disagree with "prefer `new`". If you use `new` in modern C++ you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @nwp First of all, I never mentioned `new`. Secondly, closures do not necessarily capture state and are therefore already including capture-less lambdas (which is presumably what "anonymous functions" is meant to designate), so enumerating those seperately seems superfluous.

Comment: @Columbo The comment about `new` was meant for Basille Starynkevitch, maybe I should have made 2 comments. I agree with your point that lambdas include anonymous functions and therefore anonymous functions didn't need to be mentioned separately, but I don't see anything wrong with answering your question the way I did.

Comment: @nwp I didn't disagree with your comment. I wasn't aware that anonymous functions were stateless. Mea culpa :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I am not sure recommending Free Software in general is very useful. Most free software code is actually rather atrocious, for various reasons (age, compatibility with multiple/old compilers, contributors' inexperience in C++ itself, ...)

Comment: I would not say that. Also, free software is IMHO a good example of *real world* software (in particular, I don't believe the proprietary software is significantly better). And most junior programmers start working on some existing legacy software base, not in a new project ex nihilo

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Full ACK. The proprietary code I have to cope with at work is *much, much worse* than any code I've seen in free software, yet...

Answer (score 20):

I'll just quote a paragraph out of the ISO/IEC N3690(c++ standard).

> 17.2 The C standard library
>
> 1 The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety.

So simply yes!

Answer (score 0):

yes .you can use standard c library functions in C++
Examples

```
    stdio.h   => cstdio   (printf/scanf)
    math.h    => cmath     (sqrt)
```