# What is the Relationship Between the C and C++ Standards?

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, standards, language-lawyer

I was writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539249/why-transforms-begin-s-end-s-begin-tolower-cant-be-complied-successfu/37438120#37438120) and I quoted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Parameters

> Is not representable as unsigned char and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined

When I went to inspect [the edit that had added this phrase](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Fstring%2Fbyte%2Ftolower&diff=66149&oldid=65953) I found that the author's comment:

> Can't use negative signed chars with any ctype.h function per C99 7.4/1

The author is citing from the C99 standard in C++ documentation. Is that valid? I couldn't find anything on the definition of this function in the C++ standard, so I must assume that it is valid.

But this concerns me for 2 reasons:

1. How would I know what version of the C standard the C++ standard depends upon?
2. There are lists of [the discrepancies between C and C++ everywhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-c-and-c). If I'm looking at the C standard with reference to C++ how could I possibly know whether the area I'm looking at has been overridden?

Comment: FWIW, the first description, "Is not representable as unsigned char ..." is a pretty close paraphrase of the C99 and C11 requirements. The author's comment "Can't use negative unsigned chars..." is wrong (not to mention self-contradictory). Sorry about confusing things; I didn't read your question carefully enough the first time around.

Comment: Whoops, misquoted the second comment: it's "negative signed chars", not "negative unsigned chars". Nevertheless, "negative signed chars" is simply wrong, both because negative values that are not representable as signed chars are also prohibited, and because `EOF`, which may well be representable as a negative signed char, is allowed.

Comment: related, if not even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34308279/2003898

Comment: @PeteBecker that was my commit comment, I was referring to \xb4 that I changed to unsigned with it (while also adding the mention of UB). But yes, it wasn't sufficiently pedantic.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For the first question:

The C++ standard explicitly lists the C standard(s) on which it depends in its *Normative references* section. For C++14, [intro.refs] 1.2/1 happens to list C 99:

> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999, *Programming languages — C*
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 1*
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2004(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 2*
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 3*

For the second question:

The C++ standard does not implicitly incorporate *any* parts of the C standard; all references to the C standard are explicit. A good source of information on where C++ deviates from C is Annex C, "Compatibility" of the C++ standard, particularly C.1 [diff.iso].

Additionally, references to the C standard library are scattered throughout the description of the C++ standard library (chapters 17–30 in C++14). Of particular interest can be:

- 17.2 [library.c], which describes the basic inclusion of the C standard library
- Chapter 18 [language.support], which describes many of the `<c:::>` headers of the C++ standard library (those which offer the C standard library functionality).

Answer (score 14):

> How would I know what version of the C standard the C++ standard depends upon?

In C++ 14, it's  ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (plus three corrigendums, so C99 in essence) as stated in 1.2 [intro.refs] in N4140. In C++98, it was C90, in C++17, it probably will be C11, but the C++ standard will always make that explicit.

> If I'm looking at the C standard with reference to C++ how could I possibly know whether the area I'm looking at has been overridden?

You look in the C++ standard, it either explicitly imports the C definitions minus `restrict` or any C behavior it wants or makes explicit modifications.

Usually, reading good documentation instead of the standard itself will serve you just fine.

---

To address your initial question:

> The author is citing from the C99 standard in C++ documentation. Is that valid?

Yes, because

> <sup>1</sup>
>    Tables 74 [contains `std::tolower`, me], 75, 76, 77, 78, and 79 describe headers `<cctype>`, `<cwctype>`, `<cstring>`, `<cwchar>`, `<cstdlib>`
>   (character conversions), and `<cuchar>`, respectively.
>   <sup>2</sup>
>    The contents of these headers shall be the same as the Standard C Library headers `<ctype.h>`, `<wctype.h>`,
>   `<string.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>` and the C Unicode TR header `<uchar.h>`, respectively, with the
>   following modifications [none of those apply to `std::tolower`, me]:

21.8 [c.strings] in N4140

Comment: These are very delicate matters. Please, how can one distinguish "reading **good** documentation instead of the standard itself" unless being a member of the standards committee oneself, or at least a respected author with few dozen million lines of successful code behind? Thanks, @Baum mit Augen

Comment: @user3078414 My rule of thumb: If I need to look into the standard itself to find out whether or not my code is valid, it's too complicated or smart. I mostly need the standard for stuff I cannot control, like checking the correctness of documentation on cppr (rare), or verifying some behavior in *"Just for Fun"* situations like SO and bug reports. For real code, documentation is your friend. cppr is mostly correct and cites it's sources in the standards.

Comment: For SO question tagged language-lawyer, only the standard itself counts of course, but that's one of those just for fun things.

Answer (score 3):

The edit is correct and this particular text has been in the standard since C90.

From C90 4.3

> The header  declares several functions useful for testing
>   and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int , the
>   value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall
>   equal the value of the macro EOF .  If the argument has any other
>   value, the behavior is undefined.

From C11 7.4/1

> The header  declares several functions useful for classifying
>   and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the
>   value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall
>   equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Identical text; C has always been like this. So it doesn't matter which C version your particular C++ version uses, because all C versions are equivalent.

Comment: Nit pick: 4.3 is C89 (pre-ISO) numbering. C90 made that 7.3.

Comment: @Cubbi This was from one of the "X3" C89 standards, I don't have access to ISO C90.