# How to pass in variable value in char [] in c++

Tags: c++

I have below line of code:

```
char sPostData[500] = "{\"name\":\"Test Unique Name 1\",\"salary\":\"123456\"}";
```

where instead of `Test Unique Name 1` I want to pass a variable value something like below:

```
string name = "JOHN";
char sPostData[500] = "{\"name\":" + name + "\",\"salary\":\"123456\"}";
```

But doing so it gives below error:

```
Error (active)  E0520   initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object   

Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'char []'
```

How can I resolve this issue and pass in the variable value in between. Thanks

Comment: @S Andrew You should use C string functions as memmove and memcpy.

Comment: while I totally agree with the answer from Basile below if you are really using json syntax I believe if you have more or nontrivial data to transfer in this format you should instead learn to use an already existing implementation like rapidjson

Comment: ... or _JSON for Modern C++_, they are both very good - and will save you from a lot of grief later. Since you're using Windows, you are likely to put some non-UTF8 characters in your JSON by mistake and then have a really hard time understanding why your JSON isn't accepted by the receiver.

Comment: If coming from Python, **developing such a code under Linux will make your life much easier** (in particular, since Linux is today UTF-8 and could have more libraries suitable for your needs). See also http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use some [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). So something similar to (the quoting is a bit wrong, you'll correct it)

```
std::string PostData =
  std::string{"{\"name\":"} + name + "\",\"" + salary + "\":\"123456\"}";
```

Later use `PostData.c_str()` instead of your `sPostData`....

Read also about raw [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). In your case, they are helpful.

Learn also more about [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). For example:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "{\"name\":" << name << "\",\"" << salary
   << "\":\" << pay << "}" << std::endl;
std::string PostData = os.str();
```

But  **you really should use some good [JSON](https://json.org/) library**, like [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). You probably should look into its 2<sup>nd</sup> [example](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/index.html#_example).

If you are coding something related to [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), learn more about that protocol, then consider using some HTTP client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and/or HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or a framework like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://www.qt.io/).

BTW, IMHO, **a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) is a better development platform** (even for cross-compilation) **than Windows is in your *particular* case....** (good UTF-8 support, good HTTP support, good JSON support) and many embedded hardware (e.g. [RaspBerry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)) are Linux friendly.

See also http://utf8everywhere.org/

Beware that C++ is a very difficult language. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34307848/841108) and read http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a more general insight.

Comment: Here name is the variable which I want to use. I think you made salary as variable. Sorry I am bit confused with all `{` & `""` 's

Comment: Yes, I am also confused. The good solution is to use a JSON library

Comment: That makes a lot of escaped `"`... OP and you should both check if you didn't forget to close your strings, particulary in the first one `" {\"name\":\" "`

Comment: @SAndrew
  `std::string name = "JOHN";`
  `std::string PostData = std::string{"{\"name\":" + name + "\",\"salary\":\"123456\"}"};`

Comment: Actually the reason I cannot use json is because I am passing this data to `Winhttp post request` which accepts post data in `LPVOID`

Comment: LPVOID is not a standard C++ type. You'll better code in standard C++11 or C++14, and use appropriate extra libraries *with care and caution*

Comment: The quoting don't really matter (and if it does, OP will fix that). OP needs to use a JSON library

Comment: We don't have to do the entire work for a so poorly asked -and non-researched- question. OP should do *some* of the work. If OP want me to do all his work, I would bill him. And professionally, I am expensive :-)

Comment: Apologies but I understand and I am studying few other things in this. I am very new to c++ and I come from python background.

Comment: I think you missed one `/"`, it should be `std::string PostData =
  std::string{"{\"name\":\""} + name + "\",\"" + salary + "\":\"123456\"}";`. But anyways thanks for help.