# Adding Days to a Date c++

Tags: c++, mktime

I am trying to add a certain amount of days to a date. I've looked at examples such as [Arithmetics on calendar dates in C or C++ (add N days to given date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668638/arithmetics-on-calendar-dates-in-c-or-c-add-n-days-to-given-date), but I'm still coming across this problem.

If the num_of_days is a large number, let's say 100, and the beginning day is         expire_time.tm_mday = 10. The final day is 110. So when I do mktime(&expire_time); it doesn't convert this day to a valid time; the expire_time.tm_mday still is equal to 110. I want it to add like 3 months on and be a day between 1-31. Why is this?

```
void add_num_of_days(int* month, int* day, int* year, int num_of_days) 
{
   struct tm expire_time = {};
   int date_to_days;
   expire_time.tm_year = *year - 1900;
   expire_time.tm_mon = *month - 1;
   expire_time.tm_mday = *day;

   //expire_time.tm_mday = 15;
   //num_of_days = 40;
   expire_time.tm_mday += num_of_days;

   mktime(&expire_time);

   //expire_time.tm_mday = 55! (NOT WHAT I WANT).
   *day = expire_time.tm_mday;
   *month = expire_time.tm_mon + 1;
   *year = expire_time.tm_year + 1900;
}
```

The calling code:

```
month1 = atoi(start_date.Mid(0, 2)) + 1;
day1 = atoi(start_date.Mid(2, 2));
year1 = atoi(start_date.Mid(4)) + 1900;
//Add the number of days the license 
//period is for to the start date.
add_num_of_days(&month1, &day1, &year1, atoi(num_of_days));
```

Start date:

```
//First 32 bits is for the starting date.
CString start_date = get_start_date(byte_array.Mid(0, 32));
//Example start_date would be 01152016 for Jan 15th 2016.
```

Comment: On what platform are you? What compiler and standard library are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Everything works as expected on my end (MSVC 2013 Update 4).

Comment: Works fine [here](http://ideone.com/gaVMmX). What does the calling code look like?

Comment: @molbdnilo attached the calling code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm using MSV 2012 Update 5

Comment: @user3529319 Can you show, then, how is `start_date` constructed? In what format it's in?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I edited it.

Comment: @user3529319 Why must we ask for every little piece at the time? Please post [mcve], since with every "edit" you explain how one part of your code is constructed, but introduce another, unknown variable.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The code for formatting the byte array is too much. That's why I said an example return value for start_date is 01152016 for Jan 15th 2016. Shouldn't need the code before that.

Comment: @user3529319 Yeah, I already figured as much. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of `mktime(&expire_time);`. According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) it returns `-1` if calendar time cannot be represented, so in that case your input parameter is unchanged.

To avoid such problems you may change your procedure to:

```
bool add_num_of_days(int* month, int* day, int* year, int num_of_days) 
{
   struct tm expire_time = {};
   int date_to_days;
   expire_time.tm_year = *year - 1900;
   expire_time.tm_mon = *month - 1;
   expire_time.tm_mday = *day;

   expire_time.tm_mday += num_of_days;

   if (-1 == mktime(&expire_time))
   {
      return false;
   }

   *day = expire_time.tm_mday;
   *month = expire_time.tm_mon + 1;
   *year = expire_time.tm_year + 1900;
   return true;
}
```

And then checking the return value of your function on invocation.

---

And, now let's get to the reason **why** the `mktime` says that it can't convert your date.

When you are using `01152016` as your input date, the year in the date is `2016`. However, when you are converting from the string to an int, you add additional `1900` to it (`year1 = atoi(start_date.Mid(4)) + 1900;`), making the date equal to `3916`. Apparently, that is too far in the future than `mktime` can handle (my guess would be, that it can't represent your date within the size limits of `time_t`).

Note, even though you subtract the year `1900` in your function, to `mktime` the year is still equal to `3916`, since [tm.tm_year](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) is defined as "years since 1900", so when you have 2016 years after the year 1900, it is still equal to 3916.

Comment: I was just looking into this being the problem. So thank you!

Comment: Well, I do subtract 1900 from the year before I do mktime(&expire_time) so there must be some other reason, so I will keep looking.

Comment: @user3529319 The reason is still the same. Please look at the example in the `mktime`s documentation that I linked to, since [tm.tm_year](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) is defined as "years since 1900", so your effective year value, that is passed to the `mktime` is unchanged (=3916). I will edit the answer. to account for that.

Comment: time_t is a signed 32 bit in most cases, which means the last year that can be represented by it is 2038. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) Most systems are moving to a 64 bit int though, which will roll over in about 292 billion years.

Comment: @RobK I tried to check if the size of `time_t` is clearly defined before posting this answer, but, apparently, it isn't. And, on my machine, size of `time_t` is 8 bytes, but `mktime` still returned an error in the use case posted by OP.

Comment: I suppose I should have said "in most historical cases". The size of `time_t` is usually controlled by `#ifdef`s which depend on the platform and compiler you're targeting and your own `#defines`.  For instance Windows is now using `__int64` for `time_t` unless you `#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T` and it has 32 and 64 bit versions of all the time functions.

Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to for a more complete discussion.